# Как работать с файловым дескриптором в GNU AS aarch64?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, arm, файловый-ввод-вывод

А как работать с файловыми дескриптором в GNU ассемблере aarch64? Я понимаю, как дергать системные вызовы из ассемблера, read, write, openat, close для меня не проблема. Но для работы с файлом нужен файловый дескриптор. Я понимаю, как передать строку в качестве аргумента системного вызова:

```
.data
textprog:
    .ascii "randomtext" // текст без \0
    len = . - textprog // длина текста

_start:
    mov x1, =textprog // передаем в качестве argv[1] текст "randomtext"
```

Понимаю, как вызвать open(), read(), close(). Догадываюсь, как работать с переменными. Но вот как быть с файловым дескриптором в ассемблере? Как его получить, как и куда применить, чем он там вообще является...

Comment: как я понял, open() возвращает файловый дескриптор. Вопрос: как получить код возврата функции в gnu as aarch64?

Comment: Файловый дескриптор это просто число. Скорее всего open возвращает его в eax. Сохраните куда то и используйте

Comment: eax-а нету даже в ПК версии GNU AS...

Comment: ой, я всегда забываю, что Вы задаете вопрос о армах. Надо смотреть, какой там регистр для возврата результата.  Посмотрите вот сюда - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/what-registers-to-save-in-the-arm-c-calling-convention - там написано r0/r1. Я бы просто отладчиком посмотрел, что там в регистрах возвращается. Если это первый файл, который открывается, то его дескриптор будет в пределах 0-10 и это легко распознать. Скорее всего для первого файла это будет 3. (0, 1 и 2 заняты под стандартный ввод-вывод)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Дальше дело за малым: отследил дескриптор через strace, затем все просто: `mov x0, #3 mov x1, =text mov x2, =textlen mov w8, #64 svc #0`